Calculating (and integrating) geodesic curvature for any embedding/diffeomorphism of the circle in $\mathbb R^2$?
Have $B$ be any diffeomorphism of the 2-ball. Then its Euler characteristic $\chi (B) = 1$.
Have $k_g$ denote the geodesic curvature. The Gaussian curvature $K$ of $B$ is equal to zero. From the Gauss-Bonnet theorem:
$$ \int \limits_B K \, dA + \int \limits_{\partial B} k_g \, ds = 2 \pi \chi (B)$$
but this simplifies to
$$ \int \limits_{\partial B} k_g \, ds = 2 \pi $$
I'm having trouble computing this geodesic curvature. Have the boundary of $B$ be any diffeomorphism of the unit circle, which can be parameterized by a curve $\gamma : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$.
This wikipedia article tells me that the geodesic curvature is the norm of the covariant derivative of the velocity vector field. However, it then states that since I have a curve in Euclidean space $\mathbb R^2$, I don't need to distinguish between the covariant and ordinary derivatives. Then I'm currently thinking of the geodesic curvature as being the 2-norm of the acceleration vector field for this curve:
$$ k _g = \left| \!\left| {d^2 \gamma \over (dt)^2} \right| \!\right|$$
here I'm treating this two norm as being the square root of the dot product of the vector with itself: $$ k _g =  \sqrt{(d^2 \gamma / (dt^2)) \cdot (d^2 \gamma / (dt^2))}$$
however I'm running into an issue: the geodesic curvature always evaluates to a positive value. Were I to integrate my acceleration vector field across the circle diffeomorphism below:

then I would imagine my integral of the geodesic curvature would be quite a bit higher than $2 \pi$. Is there some problem with the formula I'm using? What would be the correct formula here?
A formula for any embedding of the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ will suffice; no need to deal with the more sophisticated version for embeddings into more general smooth manifolds.

The Wikipedia article is completely WRONG. Both geodesic curvature and normal curvature have signs. Only the (plain) curvature of a space curve is defined to be everywhere nonnegative. For a plane curve, one talks about signed curvature when one talks about total curvature and the turning angle of the unit tangent vector.

You should use the signed (geodesic) curvature.  For a plane curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ with unit speed parametrization, the signed curvature at a point is $$\kappa = x'y'' - x'' y'.$$
Furthermore, the fact that the total curvature along a simple closed plane curve is $2\pi$ is called the Total Curvature Theorem in Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds book (corollary 9.6), which is an avatar of the observation that the rotation index of such a curve is $\pm 1$, i.e., the tangent vector makes exactly one full revolution traversing along the curve.
Edited to address comment: It is easy to derive the formula above from the definition given in Lee's book, which defines the geodesic curvature to be $\kappa_N = \left\langle D_t \gamma'(t), N(t) \right\rangle_g$ for a unit speed curve.  This simplifies in the case of a plane curve $\gamma(t) = (x(t), y(t))$: the Riemannian metric $\left\langle \cdot, \cdot \right\rangle_g$ is just the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $D_t \gamma'(t) = \gamma''(t) = (x''(t), y''(t))$.  $N$ is the unique unit vector field on the curve that is (oriented) orthogonal to $\gamma'(t) = (x'(t), y'(t))$; we may simply take $N(t) = (-y'(t), x'(t))$.  Plugging this into the formula for $\kappa_N$, we have $$\kappa_N = (x'', y'') \cdot (-y', x') = -x'' y' + y'' x',$$ which is equal to claimed expression.

Awesome, and thanks for the book recommendation. I read Lee's smooth manifolds introduction, so I'll check this out.

Incidentally, is this formula in that book from Lee? Where did you find it?

@Nate See edit above.
